# How to get sms automatically after place an order?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, order-status

I have developed one magento website.
In this, Client requirement is the customer have to get the sms after place the order.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

1. Get a service that can do SMS (really, you need a service, magento cannot do this by itself)
2. Confirm they have an API that you can communicate with to initiate the sending. (this is of course a requirement in making teh choice in step 1)
3. Check if someone had not already create an extension for you to use (a potential requirement in selecting your service in step 1)
4. Alternatively create your own extension for that service, using their API

4.1 if you intend to use your own code, your use the event `sales_order_invoice_save_after` to initiate your sms (this event ensures payment was taken) or if you don't care about that, simply use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`  - there are other events, just don't recall them off the top of my head right this moment.